# Change permission of the multiple items

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript, csom

I'm trying to conditionally change permission of the multiple items in SharePoint 2010 Forms Library. I've found the working code in MSDN (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185013(v=office.14).aspx) which can change the permission of the item, but don't know how to apply it for multiple items.

Comment: afaik is not possible to change it for multiple items ootb. You have to call the method (that does the trick) several time (one time for item)